# Prevent MORE records returned by JOINING a lookup table?

Tags: sql-server, join

I am having a problem. My Lookup table is producing MORE records than my original query..

I feel I am missing something basic. How do I prevent ending up with more records by bringing in a column or two from the 2nd table?

```
-- 140930
SELECT COUNT(ID)
FROM dbo.USER_ACCOUNTS AS A 

-- 143324
LEFT JOIN dbo.DOMAIN AS B 
ON A.Domain = B.DOMAIN
```

As you can see my count grows to 143324 after the join. I have tried outer joins as well. There are only 150 or so domains to join on. AND some should not even be in the results because no domain match should be found!?

This is SQL SERVER 2008 R2

|Thanks|

Comment: cant you use inner join?

Comment: @AshReva Inner Join also produces 143324 records

Comment: Are you sure you have no (zero) duplicates in your lookup table that would be creating additional records?

Comment: That means that for at least some domains in Table A, there are multiple rows for that domain in Table B.

Comment: What does `SELECT Domain FROM dbo.Domain GROUP BY Domain HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` return?

Comment: Do a select * with the same query and look at the record set. It looks like table B may have more than one record in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(ID)
FROM dbo.USER_ACCOUNTS AS A 
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM dbo.DOMAIN AS B
  WHERE A.Domain = B.DOMAIN
)
```

Comment: Even though this fixes the `COUNT` result, op said: *bringing in a column or two from the 2nd table?*, and this doesn't do that